# Checking State before calling activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Sometimes calling

```
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()
```

results in an error in particular:

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this   action after onSaveInstanceState
```

What check will prevent this error from occurring?  is it enough to check

```
 !activity.isFinishing()
```

Or should one check also that activity is not stopped?

Comment: Its a bug, this blog post explains it http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html